# Jquery appending to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to append to a div with an ID that is dynamic

```
                <script>
                    var GameId = "{{$match['gameId']}}";
                    var Ts = '{{$match['createDate']}}';
                    var TsInt = parseInt(Ts);
                    var timeSinceGame = moment(TsInt).fromNow();
                    $('#'+GameId).append(timeSinceGame );
                </script>
```

the script is run inside of a php foreach loop.

the div ID is set the same as GameID variable 
however nothing is appended to anything when run what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your jQuery is wrapped in DOM ready events, so the elements are likely not in the DOM yet when the code runs.

Try adding a DOM ready wrapper:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var GameId = "{{$match['gameId']}}";
        var Ts = '{{$match['createDate']}}';
        var TsInt = parseInt(Ts);
        var timeSinceGame = moment(TsInt).fromNow();
        $('#'+GameId).append(timeSinceGame );
    });
</script>
```

`$(function(){` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`

The alternative is to simply inject your code *after the elements* in the page, so that they do already exist.